ECC RAM prevents POST
I have an Asus M4A79XTD EVO. The manual says it supports 4x4GB unbuffered ECC. However, it won't POST (not even a beep) with any of the 4 sticks I've tried (works fine with non-ECC). The RAM I'm trying is OWC1333D3W4M16K (https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01K22UEV0). Did I get the right RAM?

Does another system work with the RAM? Do you know the RAM is good? Use one of the many good RAM compatibility guides online to confirm compatibility.

No other system with which to check the RAM. I don't know the RAM is good but it's new and I tried all 4 sticks I have individually. I'll search for RAM compatibility guides. Thanks.

There are sites that list appropriate RAM, such as Kingston (https://www.kingston.com/en/memory) and Crucial (https://www.crucial.com/store/crucial-advisor-trust). Use due diligence before purchase.

Both sites list zero compatible memory (https://www.kingston.com/en/memory/search/model/57872/asus-m4a79xtd-evo-motherboard and https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/asus/m4a79xtd-evo).  I understand motherboards can be finicky and I'll keep looking but are there any obvious incompatibilities with what I bought (as I'm gonna need to explain my return)?

https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/socketAM3/M4A79XTD_EVO/M4A79XTD_EVO_QVL.zip?model=M4A79XTD%20EVO
